# How to get name from http get angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
var array = [];

$http.get('v1/someset')
        .then(function(data) {

          if(data){
            mysize = data.data.size;  
            mysize.filter(function(e) {
              array.push(e.name);
            })
          }
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error", error);
        })
```

mysize =>

```
{id: "1", some_id: "1", name: "Small", active: "1"},
{id: "2", some_id: "1", name: "Medium", active: "1"}
{id: "3", some_id: "1", name: "Large", active: "1"}
{id: "4", some_id: "1", name: "X-large", active: "1"}
{id: "5", some_id: "1", name: "XX-large", active: "1"}
{id: "6", some_id: "1", name: "XXX-large", active: "1"}
```

How to get name from http get angularjs
It should only return

['Small', Medium, 'Large', 'X-large', 'XX-large', 'XXX-large' ]
and could accessible outside then

Comment: JS `filter` needs to be assigned to a variable again, write it as: `mysize = mysize.filter(...)`. To return it, you need `return $http.get(...)` and `return mysize` inside it. And you **cannot** access it outside of then. It is a Promise and can be **resolved** only as `promise.then(function(mysize){var array = mysize;})` whenever you need to use it again

Answer (score 1):

```
const mysize = [
{id: "1", some_id: "1", name: "Small", active: "1"},
{id: "2", some_id: "1", name: "Medium", active: "1"},
{id: "3", some_id: "1", name: "Large", active: "1"},
{id: "4", some_id: "1", name: "X-large", active: "1"},
{id: "5", some_id: "1", name: "XX-large", active: "1"},
{id: "6", some_id: "1", name: "XXX-large", active: "1"},
]

const names = mysize.map(i => i.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you Should use map to create the arr type you wish

```
var array = [];

$http.get('v1/someset')
        .then(function(data) {

          if(data){
            mysize = data.data.size;  
            //array is not the same as the array on the top
            array = mysize.map(function(item){
             return item.name
            })
          }
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error", error);
        })
```

to return the data you should return a promise

apiService.js

```
var getData = $http.get('v1/someset')
            .then(function(data) {

              if(data){
                var mysize = data.data.size;  
                var array = mysize.map(function(item){
                 return item.name
                })
                 return Promise.resolve(array)
              }
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log("Error", error);
                return Promise.reject(error)
            })
```

and the one that calls the data from the controller should do this

```
scope.data = []
apiService.getData().then(function(data){
   //scope is accessible here
   scope.data = data
})
```

Comment: array is blank don't know why if i calling it outside http.get

Comment: http.get will be run asynchronously. If you try to access array before the http.get completes, you'll get `[]` as you have declared it to be empty in the first line.

Comment: Yes, thats true but i am calling it after get request i want this globally to all service or controler

Comment: @Jacob you can't, it's asynchronous. If you have some kind of navigation modules like `ngRoute` / `ui.router`, then you can try to sync it with `resolve` and then inject it into your controllers. Otherwise you would have to resolve it as a Promise every time

Comment: you need to return the promise and save the data on the Objects scope.